# SharePoint 2010: Programmatically updating WebPartZone Properties in Page

Tags: development, web-part-zone

Is there a way to programmatically update the properties of a WebPartZone (e.g. AllowLayoutChange etc.) in a publishing page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not!

Unless, you dynamically create/update the page layout...